# How to convert all tif files in one folder to pdf and save in another location without looping through, in bash script?

Tags: bash

```
find /home/folder1/folder2/folder3/my\ Raw\ Data/"$1"/"$2"/"$3"/"$4" -type f -name "*.tif" -exec bash -c 'tiff2pdf "$1" -o "${1%.tif}".pdf' - '{}' \;
```

This is my bash script to convert tif files in `/home/folder1/folder2/folder3/my\ Raw\ Data/"$1"/"$2"/"$3"/"$4"` to pdf .The output pdf will also get saved in same location, But
I want the output pdf in `/home/folder1/folder2/folder3/my\ Raw\ Data/"$1"/"$2"/"$3"/backup`.
How is it possible without using a loop? Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Are your TIFF files all in one directory or not? Do you want the PDF written in a subdirectory called `lower` of the directory where the TIFF is? Or do you want it written in a directory `../lower` relative to the TIFF?

Comment: yes, my tiff files are within one folder $4.I want the pdf files outside $4,in another folder backup. eg : my input is in `/home/folder/tifs/x.tif` my output : `home/folder/backup/x.pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to get them all done in parallel, without any loops, using **GNU Parallel**:

```
cd /path/to/tiffs && parallel tiff2pdf {} -o ../backup/{.}.pdf ::: *tif
```

Try like this first to see what it would do, without doing anything:

```
cd /path/to/tiffs && parallel --dry-run tiff2pdf {} -o ../backup/{.}.pdf ::: *tif
```

---

Here's another way with **ImageMagick**:

```
cd /path/to/tiffs && magick mogrify -path ../backup -format PDF *tif
```

Comment: Tried GNU Parallel, Working finr for me...Thank You SO much

Comment: There's an excellent PDF guide to **GNU Parallel** here... https://zenodo.org/record/1146014/files/GNU_Parallel_2018.pdf?download=1

Comment: I tried `ImageMagick` as well.But getting error like `magick: command not found`.Tried to install the package using `sudo apt-get install -y imagemagick`, still getting same error

Comment: And also one more doubt.After tif to pdf conversion i am looping through each pdf files inside backup folder for compressing the pdf file.Is that possible since `GNU Parallel` command is running parallel

Comment: I am no sure what you are asking. As soon as the `parallel` command I suggested finishes, all the PDFs will have been created and can be compressed. You may as well compress them with **GNU Parallel**, i.e. `cd /path/to/PDFs && parallel gzip ::: *pdf`

Comment: As regards **ImageMagick**, you may be using an old v6 **ImageMagick**, in which case just drop the `magick` at the start of the command I gave and start straight in with `mogrify ...`